# Do user events get spawned on separate threads in Cocos2d / Objective C

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocos2d-iphone

I have scheduled a repeating callback on every frame:

```
[self schedule:@selector(nextFrame:)];
```

This forms my main game loop.

When a user touches the screen, an event is generated, e.g.

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ...
    // Respond to event
    ...
}
```

1. Is this event generated instantaneously on a new thread?
2. ...or is it queued and occurs when the current frame is finished?
3. ...or something else?

If it is 2. then then does this mean there are no multi-threading issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) All cocos2d-iphone code is handled within a single main game loop, ccTouchBegan is called by the Director when an iPhone SDK touch event occurs.

2) All "events" are handled before the frame is processed, rendering is the last thing that is done.

3) ...

There are no multi-threading issues in Cocos2D.

Comment: correction - there could be multi-threading issues caused by code you write that triggers multiple threads to occur, but if you write your game properly using standard cocos2d-iphone methods (schedule, scheduleUpdate, ccTouchBegan, etc) then threading issues are not a concern.